# Visual C++ BinaryReader in Java

Tags: java, visual-c++, binarystream

is there any method in java which would implement the same function as [BinaryReader()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) in Visual C++

Comment: Maybe check `BufferedReader`?

Comment: @Gaara i m very new to programming. i have been searching for a method to read a binary file in which numerical data,( floating point data both positive and negative) is stored in 16 bit form. now, i have been researching a lot but somehow i have not been able to do that. every time i am getting wierd results. I am running short on time, so please don't get irritated and help me.

Answer (score 1):

That would be [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html)

.....

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface DataInput
```

> The DataInput interface provides for reading bytes from a binary
>   stream and reconstructing from them data in any of the Java primitive
>   types.
>
> All Known Implementing Classes:
>       DataInputStream, ImageInputStreamImpl, ImageOutputStreamImpl, ObjectInputStream, RandomAccessFile

Also, you are looking for a Class in Java, not a method (as BinaryReader is a Class and not a function in C++)

[JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had a need for this and wrote an equivalent class.

https://gist.github.com/vangorra/9470810

It is essentially an implementation of .Net's BinaryReader in java. It does not have every method implemented, but provides a good start for anybody who needs to go down this path.

Example of what this class can do:

```
BinaryReaderDotNet reader = new BinaryReaderDotNet(new FileInputStream(new File("blah.bin")));
reader.readInt32(); // returns int
reader.readUInt32(); // returns long
reader.readInt16(); // returns int (first bits are zeroed)
reader.readUInt16(); // returns int (first bits are zeroed)
reader.readString(); // returns a string.
reader.readBoolean(); // returns a boolean
reader.readSingle(); // returns a float
```